# Pythonic way to check if two list of list of arrays are equal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two lists of lists of numpy arrays called A and B and I want to check that for each list inside A, there exists a list in B that is the same (contains the same arrays).

**Here's an example.**

A = [[np.array([5,2]), np.array([6,7,8])], [np.array([1,2,3])]]
B = [[np.array([1,2,3])], [np.array([6,7,8]), np.array([5,2])]]

**Basically, I was wondering if there is a pythonic/elegant way to write a function that f(A, B) == True.**

Why it should be True?
A[0] = [np.array([5,2]), np.array([6,7,8])]. There is a matching list in B.
B[1] = [np.array([6,7,8]), np.array([5,2])]
A[0] and B[1] both contain exactly the same set of vectors: np.array([6,7,8]), np.array([5,2]).

A[1] = [np.array([1,2,3])]. There is a matching list in B.
B[0] = [np.array([1,2,3])].
Therefor, return True.

Some context:

1. A and B are two clusterings of the same data.
2. A and B have the same number of clusters so A and B are the same length.
3. A[0] is a list of arrays representing all the vectors that belong to the 0th cluster in the A clustering.

Basically, I want to check whether A and B clustered the data into the same clusters. I'm not sure whether I can simply compare A[i] and B[i].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally, I wanted to know if there was an **elegant**, Pythonic way to check if two lists A and B grouped the numpy arrays into the same lists, regardless of the order. I wanted to avoid converting the numpy arrays to lists just to make the comparison. However, based on the responses I received, it seems that converting the arrays to lists is the most elegant way. Here is my code after converting the arrays to lists using array.tolist() :

```
for cluster in A:
    if cluster not in B:
        return False
return True
```

If anyone has improvements or criticism please comment. 
Also, what is the overhead of converting an array to list using array.tolist()?

Answer (score 2):

Try use [numpy.array_equal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html),
you can use code like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array_equal(np.array([[1,2],[2,1]]), np.array([[1,2],[2,1]]))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
all(A[i] == B[i] if len(B) == len(A) else False for i in range(len(B)))
```

---

```
>>> A = [[5, 2], [6, 7, 8]]
>>> B = [[5, 2], [6, 7, 8]]
>>> all(A[i] == B[i] if len(B) == len(A) else False for i in range(len(B)))
True
>>> A.append([56, 2])
>>> all(A[i] == B[i] if len(B) == len(A) else False for i in range(len(B)))
False
>>>
```

Comment: I tried your solution with the following: a = [np.array([5,2]), np.array([6,7,8])] and b = [np.array([6,7,8]), np.array([5,2])]. However, it returned False while I want it to return True. Both a and b contain the same vectors so I want to return True.

Answer (score 0):

From your latest modification it evident that your list elements are neither hashable nor ordered. A much simpler solution is to change your numpy.ndarray to list then you can sort the two lists for easier comparison. In case of `A` and `B` this means

```
In [141]: A_sorted_list = sorted([sorted([list(j) for j in i]) for i in A])
In [142]: B_sorted_list = sorted([sorted([list(j) for j in i]) for i in B])
```

Then do the comparison between the two lists

```
In [143]: all([all(i==j) for i, j in zip(A_sorted_list, B_sorted_list)])
Out[143]: True
```

If changing the array into list is a problem, you can have a helper function for comparing clusters:

```
def compare_clusters(cluster_A, cluster_B):
    for aj in cluster_A:
        aj_included = any([all(bj==aj) if len(bj)==len(aj) else False  for bj in cluster_B])
        if not aj_included:
            return False
    return True
```

the you can compare `A` and `B` as:

```
In [149]: all([any([compare_clusters(ai, bi) for ai in A]) for bi in B])
Out[149]: True
```

Comment: Sorry if I did not ask the question clearly. The np.array represents a vector so the order of the elements in the np.array matters. So C is different from A and B.

Comment: @mkim123 I have modified my answer based on your clarification.